# How do I display a byte array as an array of hex bytes or unsigned decimal numbers in the Eclipse Java debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, types, debugging

I want to view a byte array in the Eclipse (Helios Release, build id: 20100617-1415) Java debugger as an array of hex bytes (2 digits each) or unsigned decimal numbers?  Is that possible?  How?

For example, I want to display this:

[image]

...as: 0, 48, 71, 22, 139, 166, ...

...or as: 0x00, 0x30, 0x47, 0x16, 0x8B, 0xA6, ...

(This is a similar question to "[How do I display a byte array as a char array in the Eclipse Java debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919941/how-do-i-display-a-byte-array-as-a-char-array-in-the-eclipse-java-debugger)".)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not exact what you want but as I know in DEBUG MODE, there is an option for primitive Types (int, long,...).

> Switch to Debug perspective.
>    In the Variables view click the
>   "menu" item (triangle item before
>   minimize) and select "Java  Primitives...".
>   
>   In the Dialog you can choose between Hex
>   view, Ascii view and unsigned (for
>   byte).

Found this, maybe help: [Inside the Memory View](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-MemoryView/index.html)

On 3.7 (and maybe earlier), go into preferences, type "primitive display" in the filtering area, and choose to display hex values.

Comment: I can't figure out how to bring up a menu with "Java Primitives…"

Comment: Ah, I found Java Preferences, and then found "Display hexadecimal values" and "Display unsigned values" under "Primitive Display Options".

Comment: Yes, on 3.2.x have that option in Settings, same way from the "menu" on triagle > Setting...A bit difference since mine is 3.1.x

Answer (score 9):

Updated answer in Eclipse Kepler 4.3:

In the `Debug` perspective, the `Variables` tab will have:

- `View Menu` (a downward triangle),
- `Minimize` (a line), and
- `Maximize` (a window) icons in the upper-right corner.

Steps:

- Click on `View Menu` > `Java` > `Java Preferences...` to bring up a menu.
- In this menu select `Java` > `Debug` > `Primitive Display Options`.
- Check `Display hexadecimal values` and then click `OK`.
- You should now see hex values in brackets in the `Variables` tab.

Comment: Alternatively, you can go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data views > Java > Show hex value for primitives. After checking this checkbox, you can expand the variable in the debugger tab and will see both the byte/int value and the hex value.

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ IDEA 14, displaying of hex values in arrays in debugger can be enabled with *Settings → Debugger → Data Views → Java → Show hex values for primitives*.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a Watch Expression:

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b: buf) {
      sb.append(String.format("%02x, ", b & 0xff));
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
    return "[" + sb + "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse neon IDE

Displaying values in hexadecimal format

goto **Windows** -> **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Debug** -> **Primitive Display option** -> Display  Hexadecimal values(byte,short,char,int,long)

enable  the option and press *OK*

NOTE: This works in debug mode