# How do I display a char array as an array of hex bytes or unsigned decimal numbers in the Eclipse Java debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, types, debugging

This is exactly the same question as "[How do I display a byte array as an array of hex bytes or unsigned decimal numbers in the Eclipse Java debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939461/how-do-i-display-a-byte-array-as-an-array-of-hex-bytes-or-unsigned-decimal-number)",
except it applies to `char[]` rather than `byte[]`:

So, how would I view a ***`char`*** array in the Eclipse Java debugger as an array of hex bytes (2 digits each) or unsigned decimal numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, (see [Tips and Tricks for Debugging in Eclipse](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli)), you can edit and make your own formatter for any kind of value:

[image: detail formatter]

(In Eclipse preferences under **`Java->Debug->Detail Formatters`**).

That will transform, for instance, this:

[image: variable before formatting]

into this:

[image: result after custom formatting]

You could then use this technique for your char[], provided you did set first the "as the label for all variables" option

[image]